# Display only processes by a user in htop?

Tags: htop

How can I display only the processes of a specified user in `htop`?

Applying a filter (`F4`) doesn't seem to work, because it doesn't seem to apply the filter on the USER column.

Comment: F6 and you can sort by USER instead. Just use the arrow keys to select "USER" and then press Enter. It's not the same but at least it's alphabetical so each USER is isolated and easily distinguishable.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

From [`man htop`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/htop):

```
   -u --user=USERNAME
          Show only the processes of a given user
```

So, if you run `htop -u colord`, you'll only see processes by the user `colord`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that'll do nicely for my situation too. I would love a way to switch on the fly though, rather than having to go out and back in, so if anyone knows of a way I'm all ears!

Comment: @spookypeanut See [Domi's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/728642/234374).

Answer (score 61):

Another possibility is to press the 'u' key in htop. A selector that allows you to filter the process list by users will be displayed.